# VimDiff incorrectly showing all lines as changed

Tags: vimdiff, git, plugin-fugitive

I am using Vim with [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin.

Sometimes when diffing files versus their HEAD version from Fugitive's `Gstatus` window, Vim shows all lines in a file as changed, when in reality only one or two lines are different (and command-line `git diff` shows differences correctly). Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you provide an example where this happens? I would think this question is more suited as an issue for fugitive?

Comment: Is it possible that you have an issue with the end of line characters? When different people edit a file, some on windows and some on linux the end of line character are not the same and it can cause this kind of issue.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg - thank you for your comment. I'll try to show an example. The problem is that it's difficult to reproduce the problem. I'll monitor my workflow until the problem appears, so that to have more concrete steps.

Comment: @statox - I am checking it.

Comment: I run into something that sounds like this when I'm looking at many diffs, one after another. What's happening is more than 2 files are in diff mode. You can disable diff mode in all buffers with `:bufdo diffoff`.

Comment: @tommcdo - your suggestion helped! Can you please format your comment as an answer, so that i can mark it as accepted? I am wondering though, is this a bug? I was just trying to commit a dozen or so files, and had to `:bufdo diffoff` twice, as the issue got reproduced twice with different files.

Comment: @siphiuel I'm not sure if it's a bug or a workflow issue. From a Vim perspective, there's only ever one set of files being diffed against each other, so every buffer in diff mode is contributing to a single diff. I used to run into this a lot, but I don't anymore. Are you using the latest version of fugitive? (I'll post my answer once I'm at a full keyboard)

Comment: @tommcdo: just checked - my fugitive version is the latest. Weird though, i've tried reproducing it again, but it's difficult to spot a pattern. Sometimes it works until 3rd or 4th consecutive diff, and then breaks. But it's not a regular behaviour. Given that there's a single diff files set (i'd love to find out more about it), then it would seem it's an issue with Fugitive, in that it does not properly close diff buffers? (sorry if this sounds stupid, i am a total beginner)

Comment: @tommcdo There are also two Fugitive issues [#36](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/36) and [#91](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/91) that reference the same kind of problem. You've been active in the first thread as well)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the most likely culprit is another buffer still in diff-mode. This can happen if you're looking at multiple diffs, one after another, and don't turn off diff-mode between diffs.

### Disable diff-mode in irrelevant buffers

The solution is to find the offending buffer(s) and turn off diff-mode with `:diffoff`. If you don't want to search for it, you can use `:bufdo diffoff`. `:bufdo` visits each buffer sequentially and runs the command provided. This can have the unwanted side-effect of leaving your window displaying a different buffer after running the command.

Comment: Two things: (1) `diffoff!` does not reset all vimdiff configs. (2) "This can have the unwanted side-effect of leaving your window displaying a different buffer after running the command" - always wondered why, and how to fix it.